# Julia: use cases for `import` and `using`

Tags: julia

So I read the [documentation for `using` and `import`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Summary-of-module-usage) in Julia. However what this does not tell me is how I should be using these two statements in practice (and, given the lack of orthogonality, this is not too easy).

Case in point: let's put the following trivial code in `"myfile.jl"`:

```
module MyModule
f() = 1
export f
end
import .MyModule # or: using .MyModule
```

- if I use `import` on the last line, then `f` is not exported to `Main` namespace. However, when I change `"myfile.jl"` (e.g. modifying the return value of `f`) and then re-`include` it, the function is replaced (this is the behaviour I wish for). *(Note that I could explicitly `import .MyModule: f`, but this introduces unneeded redundancy; also, the real-life case will involve a long list of functions with long names. OK, I might also write a macro that uses `names(Main.MyModule)`, but I somehow feel that this ought to be simpler.)*
- if I replace `import` by `using`, then this is reversed: `f` is now exported, but changing anything in the module now requires re-starting the Julia interpreter.
- using both `import` and `using` exports only the first version of `f()` to the main namespace: when I update the code, only the first return value is used.

So my question is not about the behaviour of both statements `import` and `using`, which are documented (if not *explained*) in the linked page, but about the intent behind these. Why two statements when one would be enough? Why does one of these ignore all `export` directives? In which case am I supposed, in practice, to use each statement?

(version is 1.1.0. Also, this runs on a system without easy `Pkg` access, so I did not try `Revise` yet.)

Answer (score 11):

The convention in Julia is to use `using PackageName` unless you have some specific reason to do otherwise.

This language design decision is motivated simply by users' comfort. Julia is using multiple dispatch and typically packages export functions that operate on typed arguments (those are however usually `abstract` types so functions functionality is not limited).

With this design all functions and methods implementing them can be in the same namespace since they differ on parameter types that are specific for their packages. Hence, a scenario where `using` brings a package to the namespace that overrides existing method implementations are very rare (and then Julia reports a warning). This process is additionally controlled by package authors through using the `export` keyword.

I think that it looks *strange* to you because you are accustomed to languages like Python. For an example `numpy` has the exactly the same function names as the default functions and there is no good way to name them differently (e.g. try to think what would be a good alternative for a function named `sin` :-) ). Hence, in Python you always need to import functions into their own namespaces perhaps with an alias such as `import numpy as np`. After having several years of experience with both languages I would say that the way Julia does it is natural and the Pytonish way is strange :-)

Regarding `import` and possibilities of bringing single functions from a package to your namespace, I see it as workarounds for situations where a name clash occurs. Also you need to explicitly do that if you want to add new method implementations to some other package (like defining a new meaning for the `+` operator). Other than that you just type `using` and never look back.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to add, in addition to Przemyslaw Szufel's answer. When you are extending a method, it's possible to do that without using `import` for the function that you are extending. For example, if I want to extend `f` from the module `Foo`, I can do `using Foo` and then define a new method for `Foo.f`. Here's a complete example:

```
module Foo
    struct A
        x::Int
    end

    f(a::A) = a.x + 1

    export A, f
end

using .Foo

struct B
    x::Int
end

Foo.f(b::B) = b.x + 2
```

The advantage of this approach is that when you are reading the code it is easier to see the origin of the function that you are extending.

Comment: Why is there a dot in `using .Foo`?

Comment: `Foo` is declared in the namespace of `Main` rather than it's own package. `using .Foo` is here a shorter version of `using Main.Foo`

Comment: BTW in this code it would be enough to write `import .Foo` although `using` is more natural here. If this code was inside a package I would prefer `import` instead.

Comment: Well, often in actual code you also want to use some of the functions in `Foo` without qualification. In other words, I typically have code where in one part I use `Foo.blah()` without qualification, i.e. just `blah()`, and then where I need to extend a function `bar` from `Foo`, then I extend the qualified form `Foo.bar`.

Comment: @Cameron Bieganek  I agree :-)